# Big Spacing into footer in Wordpress site?

Tags: php, css, wordpress

i have issue with some unexpected big spacing at [bottom of homepage](https://touchdowner.cz/digital-products/). There is showing big unwanted spacing that making my site to looks bad. I checked and found that is in this CSS class:

```
.foot-menu {
font-family: "Oswald", Tahoma, Arial;
float: right;
padding: 0 10px;
text-transform: uppercase;
```

}

but dont see CSS for spacing there. Can someone to help me how to reduce that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is your `.full` div that is causing the unwanted spacing at the bottom. At present, you are saying that you want `273px` at the top *and* bottom.

```
<div id="layout" class="full"></div>
```

You have:

```
.full {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 273px auto }
```

Change it to:

```
.full {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 273px auto 0 auto }
```